# Show a Toast from a Fragment - No suitable method for makeText

Tags: android

i have this code :-

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Tab3 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private ToggleButton toggleButton1, toggleButton2;
    private Button btnDisplay;
    public void addListenerOnButton(View v) {


        toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        toggleButton2 = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
        btnDisplay = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                result.append("toggleButton1 : ").append(
                        toggleButton1.getText());
                result.append("\ntoggleButton2 : ").append(
                        toggleButton2.getText());

                Toast.makeText(Tab3.this, result.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }

    public static Tab3 newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        Tab3 fragment = new Tab3();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3,container,false);
        addListenerOnButton(v);
        return v;
    }
}
```

it's toggle button with some messages in tab page 
and i have red lines under this section:-

```
Toast.makeText(Tab3.this, result.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with this error :-

> Error:(32, 22) error: no suitable method found for
>   makeText(Tab3,String,int) method
>   Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable (argument
>   mismatch; Tab3 cannot be converted to Context) method
>   Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable (argument mismatch;
>   Tab3 cannot be converted to Context)

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use instead of `Tab3.this`, use this: `getActivity()`

Answer (score 2):

`makeText` requires a `Context` as the first parameter

`Tab3` is a `Fragment`.  A `Fragment` is not a `Context`.  Instead of `Tab3.this`, use `Tab3.this.getContext()`

Comment: Or just `getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:
1.Declare Context as global.

```
Context context;
```

2.In onCreateView write below code:

```
 context = container.getContext();
```

3.Declare context where it need.

```
Toast.makeText(context, result.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```